# Edit a model in the show route using enable/disable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, partials

Noob here, just finished the ROR getting started tutorial,

Also, full disclosure, this question is similar to mine:

[In Rails, is it possible to use the show view as an edit view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826383/in-rails-is-it-possible-to-use-the-show-view-as-an-edit-view)

but does not answer my question

I'm trying to figure out how to use the show route to show a model, but if the user clicks on a edit button at the bottom of the block of text, then it enables editing of the current textblock for that model, and upon saving, updates that model with the newly edited text.

I'm not really asking about the jquery to do this, more so the ruby on rails code to share that show route with editing. In other words, I just want to know if this is possible to do without redirecting to another page when the edit button is pressed on the show route. If so how? (and if you have the time, how do you get the textblock to have enabled text editing?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty simple, in fact, you dont have to DO much at all.

Wrap your fields in a normal form (same as you would have in the _form.html.erb). Then hide the fields and show the values. The form will submit as normal, to the update action in your controller.

It would look something like this

```
<%= form_for @thing do |f| =%>
  <div class='field'>
    <%= f.text_field :some_attribute %>
  </div>

  <div class='value'>
    <%= @thing.some_attribute %>
  </div>

  <div class='field'>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When you want to edit, hide .values, and show .fields.

Edit: To be clear, there is no rule about whether a view can be an 'edit view', you are free to add any forms you want anywhere you want, the only thing that matters is where the form POSTs its data to.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for the quick reply, so this definitely answers the "how to enable the editing" part of my question. How would I tie in method: :patch into this logic. Would I add that in as a form with that action under your div with the class "field"?

Comment: You dont need to do anything, since the object is persisted, it will set the method to patch automatically. If the object you are going to use is ambiguous, perhaps not actually an object, then you can set the :method attribute in your form_for to whatever you want.

Comment: On second thought, I think I was just confused: so here's what I'm understanding. The code you provided would be placed in the show route, however, the form in the show route would have method: :patch and I would just toggle whether they can see the submit/edit versions of the form via the edit button.

I think this is right, not entirely sure, but thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes, you are pretty much right, the form would go into show.html.erb. The method the form will post with (post or patch) is automatically determined by whether or not the object is new or already exists, so you dont have to worry about that part. It will automatically do a patch in this case, sending your data to controller#update instead of controller#create.

Comment: oh cool! Thanks for the extra comment on that, ruby rocks!! :D